# FFMPEG Can I get the audio volume level per frame to use in an expression?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'd like to apply an expression to the scale the video input based on the audio input volume level per frame. Is this possible?

Comment: see https://superuser.com/questions/1183663/determining-audio-level-peaks-with-ffmpeg

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thanks for the link. Now I can get Peak_level per frame. Any tips how I can use that number in a scale expression?